# Return Class variable according to input String value

Tags: java, class, generics, methods

I want to create a method which takes a string argument and returns a class of that type.

For e.g. if I pass `Long` , it should return `Long.class`

psudo code:

```
private Class<?> classReturn(String className){
return new Class<className>;
}
```

**Edit:** : problem is I have values like `"String"` only. not `"java.lang.String"`

**Edit2:** I have a variable in String. I want to cast it to the above class.
For e.g.
String value="1";
String type= "Long";
I want something like this (psudo code):

```
value = (classReturn(type)) value ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Class.forName(className);
```

if you have using a short class name you need to implement a path like

The closest you can do to convert strings is to assume some convention such as valueOf or a constructor which takes a String.

```
public static <T> T parseAs(String text, String className) {
    Class clazz;
    FOUND:
    {
        ClassNotFoundException e = null;
        for (String pkg : "java.lang.,java.util.,java.math.,".split(",",-1)) {
            try {
                clazz = Class.forName(pkg + className);
                break FOUND;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                e = e2;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
    try {
        Method valueOf = clazz.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
        return (T) valueOf.invoke(null, text);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            Constructor<T> valueOf = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
            return (T) valueOf.newInstance(text);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
}

enum BuySell {
    BUY, SELL
}
public static void main(String... args) {
    for (String className : "String,Long,Double,BigDecimal".split(",")) {
        Object o = parseAs("1", className);
        System.out.println(className + " => " + o.getClass() + " as " + o);
    }
    Object o = parseAs("BUY", BuySell.class.getName());
    System.out.println("BuySell => " + o.getClass() + " as " + o);
}
```

prints

```
String => class java.lang.String as 1
Long => class java.lang.Long as 1
Double => class java.lang.Double as 1.0
BigDecimal => class java.math.BigDecimal as 1
BuySell => class Main$BuySell as BUY
```

Comment: I think loading from context classloader is better approach than Class.forName(). It keeps the Permgen clean

Comment: @Chris That's a good idea if you are using custom classes and multiple class loaders.

Comment: What about Character class ? It doesn't have valueOf(String );

Comment: For other classes you will need to write a custom conversion which suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
return Class.forName(className);
```

regarding your edit, you cannot "cast" a string value to a long value.  in order to convert a string value to some other type, then you need something more complex, like [this](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/ConvertUtils.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `Class.forName()`. However you'll need the fully-qualified name of the class, with the package.